# How to iterate through an collection that has been chunked

Tags: loops, kotlin, collections

Im trying to iterate through an list that has been chunked into 6. What will be a good way to do this

```
fun listSplit(listOfEanItems: ArrayList<String?>) {
    val newList = listOfEanItems.chunked(6)
    ItemsViewFragment().getChunkedEanList(newList)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge this list back with `flatten` which will be relatively slow but readable. Or you can just use nested loops. It will be fast but less readable

```
val chunkedList = (1..20).toList().chunked(6)

chunkedList.flatten().forEach { println(it) }

//or

for (list in chunkedList) {
    for (i in list) {
        println(i)
    }
}
```